# App Engine, JSP "No forced path servlet for /WEB-INF/home.jsp"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a GAE/J program (with JSP) which runs perfectly on dev server but when I deploy it to App Engine it returns with this:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

I use Ecplise to deploy my program.
My environment and settings:

Win 7 x64

Eclipse
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

JRE System Library [jdk1.7.0_21]

App Engine SDK 1.7.7

In the App Engine admin console log shows one "Warning":

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1c24a0b{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~4562545625ab/1.366972147789894265}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No forced path servlet for /WEB-INF/home.jsp
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:679)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and one "Critical":

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The web.xml is the following:

```
    <static-files>
        <include path="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    </static-files>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>home-jsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>home-jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/home.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: I don't do GAE, so I don't post an answer as it has some quite strange exceptions/changes on top of the standard Servlet API. But I can at least tell that your URL pattern is not valid conform the standard Servlet API rules. The `/WEB-INF` folder is not supposed to be publicly accessible as that would be a potential security leak as that folder usually contains sensitive configuration files and template/include files which should not be requested individually. Change the URL pattern to `<url-pattern>/home.jsp</url-pattern>` (and also the one in your browser's address bar) and retry.

Comment: Without the /WEB-INF part I get "Error 404 /home.jsp"

Comment: Well, if the JSP is after all supposed to be publicly accessible anyway, just move the JSP file physically outside `/WEB-INF` and get rid of the servlet config and mapping on the JSP file altogether.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it works well, both on the dev server and on the App Engine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/WEB-INF` folder is along with `/META-INF` folder not supposed to be publicly accessible as they may contain sensitive configuration files and include/tag/template files which shouldn't be requested individually. The average servletcontainer has a builtin access restriction on those folders, which explains why you couldn't access the JSP page this way even though you explicitly remapped it in the `web.xml`.

If the JSP file in question is after all supposed to be publicly accessible anyway, then placing it in `/WEB-INF` folder makes simply no sense. Just move the JSP file physically outside that folder and get rid of the whole `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` entries. This way you must be able to access the JSP by simply `/home.jsp` instead of `/WEB-INF/home.jsp`.

An alternative, especially if you require some preprocessing business logic, such as loading some data from DB which should be presented in the JSP, would be to create a servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of e.g. `/home` and forwards to the JSP file in question in its `doGet()` method. See also the 2nd Hello World example somewhere halfway in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL pattern is wrong it should /home.html for example.
You shouldn't have web-inf in your URL pattern